# Object properties return zero instead of null on web form

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, oop

I have a database table called `FlatFileSetting` that stores information about excel files such as sheet name, column count etc.

Users can edit individual rows of data in this table using a form in a .NET web application. The form is populated by getting the values from a `FlatFileSetting object`.

This works fine and textboxes are populated as expected when there is data, however when the database contains null values for integer fields the associated textbox displays 0 instead of it being empty.

**FlatFileSetting Object**

```
public class FlatFileSetting
{
    public int ColumnCount { get; set; }
    public string SheetName { get; set; }

    public void GetRecord(int FlatFileSettingId)
    {
        string myConnectionString = "Foo";
        var myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[myConnectionString].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myCommand.CommandText = "[dbo].[getFlatFileSetting]";

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FlatFileSettingId", FlatFileSettingId);

        using (myConnection)
        using (myCommand)
        {
            if (myReader["ColumnCount"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                this.ColumnCount = Int32.Parse(myReader["ColumnCount"].ToString());
            }

            if (myReader["SheetName"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                this.SheetName = myReader["SheetName"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know the reason would be to do with the `!= DBNull.Value` but if I don't include it I get an `Input String Not in the Correct format` error.

I know I can also fix this by changing all the object property data types to strings, but I need to keep them in as the same datatype.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This value can never be `null`:

```
public int ColumnCount { get; set; }
```

Because `int` is non-nullable.  So even if you never set it to anything, it will default to `default(int)` which is `0`.

This, however, can be `null`:

```
public int? ColumnCount { get; set; }
```

Or, if you prefer the longer syntax:

```
public Nullable<int> ColumnCount { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you declared ColumnCount as an integer so it is 0 by default. Try making it an int? (or nullable int) and default it to null;

Answer (score 0):

If `this.ColumnCount` is declared as an `int` it will be Zero by default - and will not allow null assignments.
If you want to preserver nulls you will need to define it as a nullable int (`int?`) then you can do this:

```
this.ColumnCount = myReader["ColumnCount"] as int?;
```

And it will be null when it is not an integer (assuming your data column is defined as an integer type).